# Who is the guy Kratos passes in the Hecatonchires prison that mysteriously disappears?

Tags: god-of-war-ascension

In the opening act of the game, while chasing Megaera through the prison on Hecatonchires, there is a man that Kratos comes across who seems to be different from most cannon fodder in that he is incredibly buff (arguably more than Kratos), and just as he's about to die, he cries to the gods for help and disappears.  Who is this mystery man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight spoilers:

> This man ends up being your character if you choose to play the multiplayer aspect of Ascension.  As he cries to the gods for help, he teleports to them, then chooses an allegiance to Ares, Hades, Zeus, or Poseidon.  As always, Kratos seems to not care at all about this strange occurrence of a man and potential ally disappearing in front of him.